# Do embedded fields count towards interfaces

Tags: go

In Golang, I can have an embedded fields inside of a `struct`. The embedded field gets "promoted", and the new `struct` gets to use all the functions of the embedded fields as if it's part of itself. So my question is, does the embedded fields' functions count towards interface implementation? For example:

```
type Foo struct {
    Name string
}

func (f *Foo) Name() {
    fmt.Println(f.Name)
}

type Hello interface {
    Name()
    Hello()
}

type Bar struct {
    World string
    *Foo
}

func (b *Bar) Hello() {
    fmt.Println("Hello")
}
```

In the code above, `Bar{}` does not implement a function named `Name()`, but `Foo{}` does. Since `Foo{}` is an embedded field inside of `Bar{}`, is `Bar{}` a `Hello` type?

Comment: Yes, why not just try it? (though you need to change the name conflict around the `Name` field and method)

Comment: https://play.golang.org/p/_ojut46OvlK

Comment: Same as Gavin, but with a function that accepts the interface as an argument
https://play.golang.org/p/0UfNKWq1t8_h

Comment: No. Fields never affect interfaces, embedded or otherwise. Interfaces are _only_ about methods. However, methods on embedded values _do_ affect interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to trace this down in the [language specification](https://golang.org/ref/spec)

Find out what it means to implement an interface in the "[Interface types](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Interface_types)" section:

> Interface types ¶
>
> An interface type specifies a method set called its interface. A
>   variable of interface type can store a value of **any type with a method
>   set that is any superset of the interface**. Such a type is said to
>   implement the interface.

Or from the section on "[Method sets](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Method_sets)"

> The method set of a type determines the interfaces that the type implements...

So what is important is the *method set* of the type you want to implement the interface. Let's see what constitutes a method set in the case of embedded fields:

The first place I checked was the section "[Method Sets](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Method_sets)", but it sends us elsewhere:

> Further rules apply to structs containing embedded fields, as described in the section on struct types.

So we go to the section "[Struct types](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Struct_types)" and find:

> A field or method f of an embedded field in a struct x is called
>   promoted if x.f is a legal selector that denotes that field or method
>   f.
>
> ...
>
> Given a struct type S and a defined type T, **promoted methods are
>   included in the method set of the struct as follows**:
>
> - If S contains an embedded field T, the method sets of S and *S both    include promoted methods with receiver T. The method set of *S also includes promoted methods with receiver *T.
> - If S contains an embedded field *T, the method sets of S and *S both include promoted methods with receiver T or *T.

So, given that the methods of the embedded field are *promoted*, they **are** included in the *method set* of the containing struct. As we saw above the *method set* of any type is what determines whether it implements an interface.